# how to get the full path of file upload control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i am using asp.net 2.0 in my project using file upload control , so browse the drive and select **the file like path(D:\user doc new 2011\Montana\MT_SUTA_2010-2011.html)**
but in my code seeing error is could not find the file path is
**(D:\Paymycheck\OnlineTaxUserDocumentation-1\TaxesDocument\MT_SUTA_2010-2011.html)** actually it is application path and take the filename only my code is

```
if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
string filepath = Server.MapPath(FileUpload.FileName);
string strHTML = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] file1 = encoding.GetBytes(strHTML);
                int len = file1.Length;
                byte[] file = new byte[len]; 

                docs.TaxAuthorityName = ddlTaxAuthority.SelectedItem.Text;
                docs.TaxTypeID = ddlTaxType.SelectedValue;
                docs.TaxTypeDesc = ddlTaxType.SelectedItem.Text;
                docs.EffectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEffectiveDate.Text);

                docs.FileName = f1;
                if (ddlTaxAuthority.SelectedValue == "FD")
                {

                    docs.Add(strHTML, file1);
                }
}
```

error occoured in this line

```
string strHTML = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
```

i can try like this also

```
string FolderToSearch = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName).ToString();
string f = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
string f1 = FileUpload.FileName;
                 string filepath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
 string strFilePath = FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
string file1234 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
string filepath = FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
```

so how to get the total path drive to file 
pls help me any one

thank u
hemanth

Comment: Nope! You can't get a full path of uploaded file.

Comment: k how to get the content in selected file string strHTML = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your are using `Server.MapPath`, which according to MSDN "`maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.`" You have to first call `FileUpload.SaveAs` method to save file on server then try to read it's content.

Comment: hi sir pls give me example i think string s=fileupload.saveas(filename);

Comment: i can use string sq =FileUpload.SaveAs(filepath); but display the error

Comment: It has no return type, try FileUpload.SaveAs(filePath) without sq =

Comment: ok sir it is working but how to read the content like string strHTML = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

Comment: File.ReadAllText(filepath); isnt this working? what is the error you are reveing?

Comment: it is working string pathq = Server.MapPath("~/");

                FileUpload.SaveAs(pathq + FileUpload.FileName);
       string path1 = pathq + FileUpload.FileName;
     
       string strHTML = File.ReadAllText(path1);

Answer (score -1):

If you want the total client side drive path like `D:\user doc new 2011\Montana\MT_SUTA_2010-2011.html` for the file `MT_SUTA_2010-2011.html` to be uploaded via `fileupload` control, then try using `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)`.

This will surely return the client side path of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work

```
string filepath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fuldExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
fuldExcel.SaveAs(filepath); //fuldExcel---is my fileupload control ID
```